# Detect when new screenshot is taken using React native, expo for android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, screenshot

We are trying to build an application which analyzes a screenshot in the background as soon as it is taken.

Platforms: React Native, expo, android

Wanted to know if there's a way to detect when a user takes screenshot and get the image as well so that the app can process it.

This (https://github.com/blend/react-native-screenshot-detector) looks like a good option but it's only available for IOS.

We are open to new suggestions as well (like continuously monitoring the gallery folder for new files)